# JSP/Javascript file upload - doesn't invoke a parent javascript function on hosting server but works in local server

Tags: javascript, jsp, iframe, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file to the server. I've embedded an iframe in my jsp. This iframe holds an action to a servlet that saves the file on the server. On processing the file, it returns a HTML output (given below) through the `response.getWriter()`.

```
private String getRespHTML(boolean isUploadSuccess, String theReturnMsg){
        StringBuilder theHTMLBuf = new StringBuilder();
        theHTMLBuf.append("<html><head>");
        theHTMLBuf.append("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=\"JavaScript\">");
        if(isUploadSuccess){
            theHTMLBuf.append("parent.uploadStatus(true, '"+ theReturnMsg + "');");
        }
        else{
            theHTMLBuf.append("parent.uploadStatus(false, 'Upload failed: " + theReturnMsg + "');");
        }
        theHTMLBuf.append("</SCRIPT>");
        theHTMLBuf.append("</head><body></body></html>");

        return theHTMLBuf.toString();

 }
```

Now this `parent.uploadStatus` (the JS function that resides in the script file included in the JSP), works perfectly in my local server. But when I host this, the upload happens well, but this script is not invoked. Here all the pages are from the same domain, and it didn't work with `window.parent.uploadStatus` even.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, my bad.
I added the following line for my servlet response and it worked.

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```